# SFML 2.4.2 VideoMode error

Tags: c++, sfml

I decided to try with SFML again but here is when a new update comes and you don't know what to do. I managed to find how to setup my SFML but here the error is when i start the program

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height, 32), "Example");
```

and here is a photo of the error and the code
[image: error]

I tried fixing it but still noting, i watched tutorials pictures of the code examples but noting happened again.
i hope you can help me with this problem.

after compiling it i got this many errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vector"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Window\VideoMode.hpp 32  1
>   Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'ostream': No such file or directory  MoonSurvival    C:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Err.hpp   32  1
>   Error (active)  E0018   expected a ')'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    150 35
>   Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Iterator" is undefined  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    479 5
>   Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ConstIterator" is undefined MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    489 5
>   Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Iterator" is undefined  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    503 5
>   Error (active)  E0020   identifier "ConstIterator" is undefined MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    517 5
>   Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    52  30
>   Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    53  30
>   Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    276 22
>   Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    286 22
>   Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    299 22
>   Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    527 22
>   Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    276 5
>   Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    286 5
>   Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    299 5
>   Error (active)  E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    527 5
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Glsl.inl    40  61
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "string"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Texture.hpp 127 34
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Texture.hpp 159 48
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "ostream" MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Err.hpp   41  22
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "basic_string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    52  18
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "basic_string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    53  18
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    58  23
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    78  38
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    78  60
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    106 47
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    106 69
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "string"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    118 23
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    118 54
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    118 76
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "wstring" MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    134 23
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "string"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    253 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    253 41
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "locale"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    253 63
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "wstring" MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    266 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "basic_string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    276 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "basic_string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    286 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "basic_string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    299 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    332 29
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    345 30
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    365 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    387 21
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    387 43
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    399 22
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    413 10
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    413 46
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    427 23
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    427 45
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    456 27
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "size_t"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    456 49
>   Error (active)  E0135   namespace "std" has no member "basic_string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    527 10
>   Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    52  13
>   Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    53  13
>   Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    150 18
>   Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    221 5
>   Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    236 5
>   Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow" matches the argument list   MoonSurvival    c:\Users\Kids\source\repos\MoonSurvival\MoonSurvival\Launcher.cpp   17  26
>   Error (active)  E0297   expected an operator    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    221 14
>   Error (active)  E0297   expected an operator    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    236 14
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vector"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\ConvexShape.hpp 33  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "map"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Font.hpp    37  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Font.hpp    38  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vector"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Font.hpp    39  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Image.hpp   34  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vector"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Image.hpp   35  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "algorithm" MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Rect.hpp    32  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\RenderWindow.hpp    35  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "map"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Shader.hpp  37  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Shader.hpp  38  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Text.hpp    38  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vector"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\Text.hpp    39  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "vector"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\Graphics\VertexArray.hpp 36  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "ostream"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Err.hpp   32  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "cstdio"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\FileInputStream.hpp   35  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\FileInputStream.hpp   36  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "cstdlib"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\MemoryInputStream.hpp 34  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "iterator"  MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    33  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "locale"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    34  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\String.hpp    35  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "cstdlib"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Thread.hpp    33  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "cstdlib"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\ThreadLocal.hpp   33  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "algorithm" MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Utf.hpp   32  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "locale"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Utf.hpp   33  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "string"    MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Utf.hpp   34  1
>   Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "cstdlib"   MoonSurvival    c:\SFML-2.4.2\include\SFML\System\Utf.hpp   35  1

and its really big, but when i saw it i touch maybe its because my project is on release not debug? i will try but for now that's the error.

[FINAL GOOD EDIT]
everything is just fine maybe i have deleted something in the properties window but i made new project and everything is  just fine

Comment: Have you tried assigning `"Example"` to a `std::string` variable before passing it to the `RenderWindow` constructor? Also, can you specify the compiler and platform you are using?

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Which compiler are you using? This line should compile fine out of the box. Also your screenshot doesn't show a runtime error, it's a compiler error. Did you try to actually compile it? If this is Visual Studio Code, for me it sometimes has issues interpreting the headers properly and you can ignore them.

Comment: Try that one from SFML webpage and check if it's working for you `sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");`

Comment: Code is correct, all params passes. Are you sure that you updated library files correct? Feels like they are corrupted and you forgot to replace some of them.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:
the compiler complains about the types of the arguments passed to videoMode, as it identifies them as integers, it basically fails to construct a Vector2u, if you create a Vector2u with '{}' preventing narrowing it will work., note that the third argument passed to the VideoMode is optional, in this case I skipped it.

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({200,200}), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
```

As a side note you may want to check the slash in the includes I think it should be:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

not

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
```

and also use C++17 or newer, as otherwise some things will fail, in my case I was using VS2022 and the default version is C++14. So optional was not part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove depth in VideoMode

```
sf::VideoMode(size,size)
```